# 2D Unity Enemy Chase/Evade script in C#

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence, unity-game-engine

Okay so I've been fighting with this script for a couple days now. I've made progress in other aspects but I can't seem to get my enemies to properly chase the player character.

The script is supposed to have the enemies wander until an empty child 'eyes' sees the player. Then it should start chasing the player. Think pac-man. What it's doing right now is making one loop of it's wander cycle and then stopping and not seeing the player at all.

This is the code that I've got so far for that script -

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class dudeFollow : MonoBehaviour {
Transform tr_Player;
float f_MoveSpeed = 3.0f;
private DudeMove moveScript;
public Transform eyes;
public float sightRange = 3f;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    tr_Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
    moveScript = GetComponent<DudeMove>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast (eyes.transform.position,eyes.transform.forward, out hit,sightRange) && hit.collider.CompareTag ("Player")) {
    transform.position += transform.forward * f_MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    moveScript.enabled = false;
        }

}
```

}

Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have 2D game, what most likely happens is your enemy wonders away on z-axis as well, but because it's 2D, you can't see it. So switch to 3D mode in your main scene window and see if that's the case.

If it is, just reset z-axis to 0 on every frame and disable angular momentum :) I had this happen with 2D games.

```
void Update () {
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast (eyes.transform.position,eyes.transform.forward, out hit,sightRange) && hit.collider.CompareTag ("Player")) {
    transform.position += transform.forward * f_MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    moveScript.enabled = false;
        }
    transform.position.z = 0; // or something along those lines, I don't remember the syntax exactly.
}
```